# How to generate FCM registration token without Firebase SDK (i.e. via REST)?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using Firebase (Realtime DB) with success by simply calling on the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database) ; because of how my app is structured ([dynamic modules / frameworks](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md)) I cannot use the Firebase iOS SDK.

I have been trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to generate remote notifications through APNs.

While I have been successful in using test tools (like [Push Notification](https://github.com/onmyway133/PushNotifications)) to send remote notifications, I can't seem to find a way to use FCM because I need a FCM registration token to [send an FCM message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Message).

Is there a REST API endpoint that can be used to generate (and "register"?) an FCM registration token ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no documented REST API to get the FCM token/instance ID for an app installation.

If you have the APNS token, there *is* an API however to exchange that for an FCM token. See https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens

Comment: Perfect ! I had tried this before but I was using the web API key (which didn't work). Instead in the "Authentication:key=YOUR_API_KEY" one needs to use the server key token from the Cloud Messaging Settings tab (in the Firebase Console). Thanks !