# Equivalent of batchImport for firebase-admin?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to move from the `batchImport` REST API ([see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62527199/7886424) to a previous question) found in the [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens) endpoints to something similar in `firebase-admin`.

The original idea was to use a database trigger from Firebase Cloud Functions to convert a newly stored iOS APNs token (from the device) to a FCM registration token.

I think I could use an HTTP request to the same Instance ID API endpoint, but I was wondering if there is an existing `admin` SDK method that would do just that (convert existing iOS APNs token to FCM registration token).

Note : there's an [`admin.instanceId`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.instanceId) documented but it doesn't look relevant to this topic.

Comment: same problem here, using firebase-admin to receiving APNS token, need to save to database as FCM one.U found better solution instead of firing rest request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the FCM Admin SDK for Node.js doesn't provide a wrapper for that REST method.

You may want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to get this feature added in the future, but for the moment you'll need to call the REST API directly to import the tokens.